# Best way to quickly and repeatedly search if value is present in a rapidly growing array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program that looks up hundreds of categories from a website and of each category it grabs data from the product detail pages of many of the products in each category

Each category I get them from a SELECT from a table with like 800 categories, and then I get like 100 products from each category.

The problem is that many of those products belong to more than one category so I am trying to put a way in my code to NOT go to the product detail page if I have already grabbed that product before(in a different category)

so the code conceptually would be something like this:

```
thesql = "SELECT catid from categories";

ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(thesql);

while (rs.next())
{
  > go check the website for this particular catid

  > loop to check all products in this page      
    > for each productid listed in this category's page:
       > check array to see if we have encountered this productid before(in
         this session)
          > if we have, skip this product and continue with next one
          > if we haven't, go to this product's detail web page, grab its
            data, insert it in database, and add this productid in our array.
 }
```

I have 2 questions:

1) Would it be counterproductive or too resource intensive to have to add one product id to such a big array each pass and also have to search each time to see if the current product id is preexisting in the array?(the array could potentially end up with 2000-6000 items)

2) If there is more than one way to go about it, what is the way you recommend?

(Please note I have very litle experience with java arrays, though I understand the concept)

I know I could just use "INSERT IGNORE INTO..." when inserting into the database table to insure I would not insert duplicates, but I want to save the time and resources needed to check websites of products that I already have checked.

Many thanks!

EDIT/UPDATE: I forgot to mention that the productid's are not numbers but strings of 10 characters, mixing letters and numbers. Not sure if it makes a big difference.

Comment: You should use an `HashSet` instead of an array. The lookup will be instant (O(1) instead of O(n) for an array).

Comment: 2000 - 6000 items are not much, and when you only need the id in that array. Why not using it, its fast and simple. But it consumes ram and it gets lost when the app crashes. When I would write such an app and the app should run frequently I would use a persistend storage to keep that data and which allows my to fast search on the data. I would recomend elasticsearch.

Comment: "*end up with 2000-6000 items*"--actually, it is not so big, in memory it takes nanoseconds to process

Comment: Arrays are not dynamic data structures in java. They do not **grow**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use a [`HashSet<Id>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) instead of an array:

> This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.

**10k items won't be a problem at all** if your `Id` implements not too intensive `hashcode`/`equals`, for instance if your ids are `Long`.

Also keep in mind that if you access web pages and perform DB calls, the amount of time spent in the Java code is most likely gonna be negligible: most of the time is gonna be spent waiting for those external calls to return.

Comment: I have updated my post. The product ids are not of numeric type, but 10 character string mixing letters and numbers, not sure if it affects the approach you suggested

Comment: "most of the time is gonna be spent waiting for those external calls to return" -> that's precisely why I want to avoid making duplicate web calls for products I already have ;-)

Comment: ``String`` is fine. ``HashSet`` is definitely the way to go anyway.

Comment: ok, thanks! I had never heard of this class. I'll learn how to use it. cheers :-)